# Running end-to-end tests with generator-angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run end-to-end (e2e) tests for an AngularJS application using Protractor.  I have created a base application with yeoman and [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).  The first time I run `grunt test:e2e`, the single e2e test runs successfully.  The second time I run the e2e tests, the tests fail with the output as shown here: https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/f2e39db0213e5fbb7fdc.  Specifically, I get the following error:

`Error: Error while running testForAngular: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result
  (Session info: chrome=38.0.2125.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301324 (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48),platform=Linux 3.13.0-35-generic x86_64)`

I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04.  Prior to running the e2e tests I configure Xvfb with:

`Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
export DISPLAY=:1.5`

If I restart my box, the test will again run fine a single time, but fail on subsequent runs.

Why do the e2e tests fail on subsequent runs?

Comment: Any resolution on this?